# Check if a field is left empty - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, field

Is there a way in Django to detect if a field is empty, and by this I mean detect if a field is left empty for every entry of a model submitted?

**EDIT:**

model.py

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.date1 is None:
            self.date1 = None
        if self.date2 is None:
            self.date2 = None

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

views.py

```
if self.date1 is None:
    print('DID IT')
```

HTML

```
{% if date1 == None %}
    <h1>1 </h1>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [intercept/override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) the [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) functionality to check if your target fields are empty before they are saved:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.some_field1 is None:
            # Do something
        if self.some_field2 is None:
            # Do something
        ...
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
...
```

Note though that if you are using [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), the `save()` wouldn't be called so you might want to handle such case differently.

Comment: I'm almost there and Ill post an update of my code when I am. I have two questions. First what exactly is bulk create? And second more importantly is what can I add where it says "Do something"? I have  .myfield == None for both of them and I have tried other variations but how do I get that in the HTML to do and if statement there?

Comment: Its in the EDIT

Comment: This code is in the model itself. What this will do is every time a new record is saved to the database, this will be called first. Thus, you can check if any of the fields are NULL (`None`) and act accordingly (which will be the logic to put inside `# Do something`). The `bulk_create` is only if you are doing `MyModel.objects.bulk_create()`.